# Create a list of date ranges from a list of dates

Tags: sql-server

We currently store a schedule of payments as follows:

```
Item No | Due Date   | Amount Due
108     | 2013-02-01 | 60.00
108     | 2013-02-26 | 60.00
108     | 2013-03-01 | 60.00
108     | 2013-03-15 | 60.00
```

*note: the difference between the dates is inconsistent, i.e. some items may be weeks, fortnights or months.*

What I ideally need to work out is how to re-query the above table into the following format:

```
Item No | Due Date   | Date From  | Date To    | Amount Due
108     | 2013-02-01 | 2013-01-14 | 2013-02-25 | 60.00
108     | 2013-02-26 | 2013-02-26 | 2013-02-28 | 60.00
108     | 2013-03-01 | 2013-03-01 | 2013-03-14 | 60.00
108     | 2013-03-15 | 2013-03-15 | 2013-03-25 | 60.00
```

The extra two dates to be fed in to allow this to be possible will be Start Date (2013-01-14) and today's date (2013-03-25).

Each range should go from the Original Due Date to the day before the next Due Date.

Any advise would be appreciated.

---

UPDATE

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
WITH 
    CTE_Repayments(AgreementID, DueDate, AmountDue)
AS 
    (
    -- Anchor Member Definition
        SELECT 
            AgreementID, StartDate, CONVERT(DECIMAL(9,2),0.00)
        FROM
            Loans AS L
        WHERE
            L.AgreementID = 111
        UNION ALL
    -- Recursive Member Definition
        SELECT
            RB.AgreementID, RB.DueDate, CONVERT(Decimal(9,2),RB.AmountDue)
        FROM
            (
                SELECT *
                FROM RepaymentBreakdown
                WHERE AgreementID = 111
            ) AS RB
        INNER JOIN
            CTE_Repayments AS R
            ON RB.AgreementID = R.AgreementID
    )

-- Statement that Executes CTE
SELECT AgreementID, DueDate,  AmountDue
FROM CTE_Repayments
```

But this does not work.

I am assuming I need to add a record with the start Date as an Anchor member.

OK it now returns Data with the amended code above.

Problem I have now is that the result set is not restricted to the AgreementID From the Anchor and I get an error:

> Msg 530, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.

Comment: What if there is no previous `Due Date`?

Comment: There is always a list of dates. Like I say, we will pass in StartDate as the first Date, every time.

Comment: Has *anything* been tried?

Comment: At this point in time no, it is just a new query I am starting to write, and was not sure on best direction to go in.

Comment: I would generate a CTE with a row number and use previous and next row to populate the `To` and `From` using `DATEADD`

Comment: hmm, I must say CTE's are not something I have used before.

Comment: Start by [reading the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972(v=sql.100).aspx). I would advise to do some research and come back with what you found.

Comment: Thats fine, thank you for your advice, I was not asking for the answer, maybe just some quick pointer references.

Comment: Original post updated.

Comment: Shouldn't the second half of the union have a where clause to exclude the anchor row(s)?

Comment: I managed to this as part of a stored procedure.

Answer (score 2):

Your error is the result of your statement hitting the default recursion limit of 100.  This can be altered by using the [`MAXRECURSION` query hint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181714.aspx).  To use the hint with no limit declared, your statement would look like this:

```
-- Statement that Executes CTE
SELECT AgreementID, DueDate,  AmountDue
FROM CTE_Repayments
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

**Warning**:  Be *very* careful using no limit on your recursion.  This limit is in place to short circuit infinite recursion loops.  Depending on how the data looks, your query could easily spin out and create other issues.  I would recommend incrementally increasing your `MAXRECURSION` above 100 to find an appropriate upper limit.  Definitely test this before putting this code into production.

Answer (score 1):

There may be a more elegant way of doing it inside the CTE, but here's my solution.

```
WITH cte (rowNo, itemNo, dueDate, amountDue) AS
( 
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [Due Date]) rowNo, 
    [Item No], [Due Date], [Amount Due]
  FROM loans
)
SELECT a.itemNo, a.dueDate,
  CASE WHEN c.dueDate IS NULL THEN '2013-01-14'
    ELSE a.dueDate END AS dateFrom,
  CASE WHEN b.dueDate IS NULL THEN '2013-03-25'
    ELSE DATEADD(day, -1, b.dueDate) END AS dateTo,
  a.amountDue
FROM cte AS a
LEFT JOIN cte AS b ON b.rowNo = a.rowNo + 1
LEFT JOIN cte AS c ON c.rowNo = a.rowNo - 1
```

**Result**

```
| ITEMNO |                         DUEDATE |                        DATEFROM |                          DATETO | AMOUNTDUE |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|    108 | February, 01 2013 00:00:00+0000 |  January, 14 2013 00:00:00+0000 | February, 25 2013 00:00:00+0000 |        60 |
|    108 | February, 26 2013 00:00:00+0000 | February, 26 2013 00:00:00+0000 | February, 28 2013 00:00:00+0000 |        60 |
|    108 |    March, 01 2013 00:00:00+0000 |    March, 01 2013 00:00:00+0000 |    March, 14 2013 00:00:00+0000 |        60 |
|    108 |    March, 15 2013 00:00:00+0000 |    March, 15 2013 00:00:00+0000 |    March, 25 2013 00:00:00+0000 |        60 |
```

[See the demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e8c8a/1)

Comment: Hi

This code is great, thank you, but I cannot get the same results when run against my database.

Comment: Maybe they also need partition in the window:? `OVER (PARTITION BY itemNo ORDER BY ...`